# How can I make pictures at the same height?

Tags: html, css

I have this site:

[link](http://bagelhousecafe.ch/)

**CODE HTML:**

```
 <div class="grid-sizer"></div>

                      <!-- # ROW-1 # -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="grid-item item-1" >
                                <img src="<?php echo ot_get_option('left1_img'); ?>" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="grid-item item-2">
                                <img src="<?php echo ot_get_option('center1_img'); ?>" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="grid-item item-3">
                                <img src="<?php echo ot_get_option('right1_img'); ?>" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      <!-- # ROW-2 # -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="grid-item item-2">
                                <img src="<?php echo ot_get_option('left2_img'); ?>" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="grid-item item-1" >
                                <img src="<?php echo ot_get_option('center2_img'); ?>" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="grid-item item-3">
                                <img src="<?php echo ot_get_option('right2_img'); ?>" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- # ROW-3 # -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="grid-item item-small">
                                <img src="<?php echo ot_get_option('left3_img'); ?>" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="grid-item item-medium" >
                                <img src="<?php echo ot_get_option('center3a_img'); ?>" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="grid-item item-small">
                                <img src="<?php echo ot_get_option('centerb_img'); ?>" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="grid-item item-2">
                                <img src="<?php echo ot_get_option('right3_img'); ?>" />
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
/* ---- grid ---- */
.item-1,.item-3{
  width:40%;
}
.grid {
  background: #DDD;
}

/* clear fix */
.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

/* ---- .grid-item ---- */
.item-small{
  width: 20% !important;
}
.item-medium{
  width: 34% !important;
}
.item-2{
  width: 25% !important;
}
.grid-sizer,
.grid-item {
  width: 37.333%;
}

.grid-item {
  float: left;
}

.grid-item img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

I put an image to better understand what they want to do.

[image]

The images must have a resolution adjustable height depending on.

I tried to `.grid-item img {height:316px;}` but the low resolution images do not look good.

What they want is to always have a fixed height equal pictures and look good on all resolutions.

Do you think you can help me to find a solution please?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Because there are several *fixed* images, you can put them in a single img. In this way you can adjust your image a priori.
Furthermore loading a single img is less expensive than loading several imgs (look on Google "css sprite")